# LazyColumn flickers on data update

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

When I update the state it seems that the whole composable recomposes and lazy column seems to be created anew (it blinks and shows new content from the very beginning) At the same time layout inspector shows that recompositions for lazycolumn are skipped. Composable is added through XML in fragment.
Full minimal app can be found here [simple test app](https://github.com/frakc/flicking_bug) which reproduces that issue

SearchCityCompose

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SearchCityCompose(
    state: State<SearchCityState>, onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit, onItemSelected: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
    ) {

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
                .widthIn(max = 640.dp)
        ) {


            Row(
                Modifier
                    .height(46.dp)
                    .background(
                        color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                    ), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = (Modifier.width(8.dp)))
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.LocationOn,
                    contentDescription = "Search city input box",
                    Modifier
                        .size(40.dp)
                        .alpha(if (state.value.query.isEmpty()) 0.5f else 1f),
                    tint = Color.Black
                )
                Spacer(modifier = (Modifier.width(8.dp)))
                val textStyle = TextStyle(
                    color = Color.Black, textAlign = TextAlign.Start
                )
                BasicTextField(
                    value = state.value.query,
                    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                        if (state.value.query.isEmpty()) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Search",
                                style = textStyle,
                                modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.5f),
                                maxLines = 1,

                                )
                        }
                        innerTextField()
                    },
                    textStyle = textStyle,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    singleLine = true,
                    onValueChange = {

                        onTextChanged(it)
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),

                    )
            }


            LazyColumn(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
            ) {

                itemsIndexed(
                    state.value.searchCities.fromServer,
                ) { index, city ->
                    val bgType by remember {
                        derivedStateOf {
                            getBgType(index, state.value.searchCities.fromServer.size)
                        }
                    }
                    CityItem(modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement(),
                        value = city,
                        bgType = bgType,
                        onClick = { onItemSelected(it) })
                }


            }
        }
    }
}

private fun getBgType(index: Int, size: Int): BgType {
    return when {
        size == 1 -> BgType.SINGLE
        index == 0 && size > 1 -> BgType.TOP
        index == size - 1 && size > 0 -> BgType.BOTTOM
        else -> BgType.MIDDLE
    }
}

enum class BgType { TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM, SINGLE }


@Composable
private fun CityItem(
    modifier: Modifier, value: String, bgType: BgType, onClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val textStyle = TextStyle(
        color = Color.Black, textAlign = TextAlign.Start
    )
    Box(
        modifier
            .height(46.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.White)
            .clickable { onClick(value) }, contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
    ) {
        Text(
            text = value, style = textStyle, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
        )

    }

}
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class SearchCityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val serverUseCase: SearchCityUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {

    private var queryState = MutableStateFlow("")
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SearchCityState())
    val state: StateFlow<SearchCityState> = _state.asStateFlow()
    private var job: Job? = null

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            queryState.debounce(350L).collect {
                job?.cancel()
                job = viewModelScope.launch {
                    serverUseCase.invoke(it).collect {
                        _state.update { state -> state.copy(searchCities = it) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun searchCities(query: String) {
        _state.update { state -> state.copy(query = query) }

        queryState.value = query
    }
}
```

SearchCityUseCase

```
class SearchCityUseCase @Inject constructor(

) {
    suspend fun invoke(query: String): Flow<SearchCity> {
        val recents = cities.take(5)
        val flow = callbackFlow<SearchCity> {
            trySend(SearchCity(recent = recents))
            delay(300L)
            val c = if (query.isEmpty()) {
                cities
            } else {
                cities.filter { it.lowercase().contains(query.lowercase()) }
            }
            trySend(
                SearchCity(
                    recent = recents,
                    fromServer = c)
            )

            awaitClose()
        }
        return flow
    }

    val cities = listOf(
        "New York",
        "Los Angeles",
        "Chicago",
        "Houston",
        "Phoenix",
        "Philadelphia",
        "San Antonio",
        "San Diego",
        "Dallas",
        "San Jose",
        "Austin",
        "Jacksonville",
        "San Francisco",
        "Indianapolis",
        "Columbus",
        "Fort Worth",
        "Charlotte",
        "Seattle",
        "Denver",
        "Washington, D.C."
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple factors causing the flicker and the frequent recomposition, mainly coming from the `SearchCityUseCase` and the list items of the LazyColumn in `SearchCityCompose`.

It looks like inside the `SearchCityUseCase`, the first callback call `trySend(SearchCity(recent = recents))` and the artificial delay `delay(300L)` are unnecessary since the `recent` list is also passed in the second callback call with the `fromServer` list, which is the list displayed in the UI afterwards. That's the reason for the visible flicker, because in the first emission the `fromServer` list is empty by default.

```kotlin
class SearchCityUseCase @Inject constructor(

) {
    suspend fun invoke(query: String): Flow<SearchCity> {
        val recents = cities.take(5)
        val flow = callbackFlow<SearchCity> {
//            trySend(SearchCity(recent = recents))
//            delay(300L)
            val c = if (query.isEmpty()) {
                cities
            } else {
                cities.filter { it.lowercase().contains(query.lowercase()) }
            }
            trySend(
                SearchCity(
                    recent = recents,
                    fromServer = c)
            )

            awaitClose()
        }
        return flow
    }
```

Inside the `SearchCityCompose`, the LazyColumn items don't have a factory key, therefore the whole list is being recomposed whenever the list changes. The inclusion of a key for each item should reduce the recomposition to a minimum.

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .weight(1f),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 16.dp)
) {

    itemsIndexed(
        items = state.value.searchCities.fromServer,
        key = { _, city -> "item_$city" }  // A factory key for each list item.
    ) { index, city ->

        val bgType by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                getBgType(index, state.value.searchCities.fromServer.size)
            }
        }
                    
        CityItem(
            modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement(),
            value = city,
            bgType = bgType,
            onClick = onItemSelected
        )

    }

}
```

Happy coding!